# how to make responsive table with bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive, css-tables

need help to make table responsive.

On this size everything is ok:
[image]

but when screen size is reduced im getting smth like this:
[image]

table is displayed on col-md-7:

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="ritekhela-fancy-title-two">
                            <h2>Turnyrinė lentelė</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="rs-point-table sec-spacer">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Vieta</td>
                                        <td class="team-name">Komanda</td>
                                        <td>Sužaista</td>
                                        <td>Perg.</td>
                                        <td>Lyg.</td>
                                        <td>Laim.</td>
                                        <td>Įm.</td>
                                        <td>Pr.</td>
                                        <td>+/-</td>
                                        <td>Taškai</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>01</td>
                                        <td class="team-name">Banani FC</td>
                                        <td>60</td>
                                        <td>35</td>
                                        <td>08</td>
                                        <td>16</td>
                                        <td>02</td>
                                        <td>04</td>
                                        <td>11</td>
                                        <td>95</td>
                                    </tr>
                                   </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**EDITED:**
If i trying to add max and min width, marked place is reducing too much:
[image]

Comment: could you please explain, what you try to achieve, output looks responsive, you might want to add an overflow:auto; together with a min-width:500px, min-height:300px; or similar, to make the page scrolling, when below that size

Comment: i want that the table size with title would be the same size then reducing screen

Comment: this is a problem you can take care of reducing font-size, table-cell width, etc. with [media-queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) but then the whole thing might become too small for a  positive check for "mobile friendly", therefore a min-width and height is recommended, like for a small smartphone 360px * 640px, whatever is smaller is scrolling

Comment: @Vickel, added additional info into post, where "EDITED:"

Comment: ok great, that makes the problem clear, it's not the table, but the header with the title which should expand to the table width. Give `.ritekhela-fancy-title-two` a width of 100%, you might need to set it to `position: absolute` (that if `.col-md-7` is set to position:relative). if you could create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a stack-snippet, it would turn helping you much easier

Comment: doesn't helped :/ i tryied to create MRE  - https://jsfiddle.net/monud4j5/ , is it ok, or i need to do something more?  really need help here, i would be very grateful, @Vickel

Comment: @Vickel, can you help me? added anotuer MRE:  https://jsfiddle.net/L07yzrnm/

Comment: I've updated my answer, it was only working on Chrome, now it should work with all browsers

Comment: You are welcome, thank you and happy new year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look into your second [example](https://jsfiddle.net/L07yzrnm/).

the troubling part is obviously your title bar, whose elements are inside the class `ritekhela-fancy-title-two`

And you have a wrapping div around this class, named `row`, this div needs to get set to adapt its width to the nested content.

Since fit-content is experimental and [not available at all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility), you'll need set width to auto and make it behave as an inline block

Then you must set the width of your `ritekhela-fancy-title-two` class to `auto` and remove the float:left, or set it to `float:none` and it will neither overflow on larger screens or not expand to the width of table on smaller screens.

that's it, check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtsufyaL/2/) with above changes implemented

these are the two css styles which were changed/added:

```
.row {
    width: fit-content; /*works with Chrome, but not with FF*/
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.ritekhela-fancy-title-two {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 60px;
    border-top: 7px solid;
    background: url(/css/images/transparent-pattren.png);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: #6c757d;
}
```

**edit:** as above changes also affect the lower title bars, which is easy to correct, adding some height to the second row:

```
.ec-nextmatch {
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    float:none;
    height:90px;
    width:auto;
}
```

also remove .ec-nextmatch from this css, so it looks now:

```
.ec-team-matches, .ec-match-countdown, .ec-match-countdown .countdown-row, .ec-ticket-button {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the hassle of reducing font sizes, table cells widths, etc. I would recommend using the Bootstrap responsive table utility, basically makes the table scroll horizontally. Can be achieved like so...

```
...
<div class="tab-content table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
...
```